# soapClient.GetList does not return CustomFields, created in Acumatica I300 course

Tags: acumatica, custom-fields

Acumatica course I190 shows how to create custom fields. I followed the tutorial and created two custom fields for Stock Items.

Acumatica course I300 has an example of exporting StockItems, procedure RetrievalOfDelta.

However, call soapClient.GetList(stockItemsToBeFound) does not return the CustomFields, even though I changed ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.All, and can see values of all other fields.

How to include the CustomFields to be returned by GetList?

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to add them in the API endpoints to show

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Could you please provide more details on how to do it, and some piece of code? Also, somewhere Acumatica manual said that Default endpoints can handle custom fields, what is your take on that?

Answer (score 0):

For guidelines on broad general topics like API Custom Fields refer to documentation.

You need to extend the default endpoint and extend the entity (stock item).

Reference: 
https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c450492e-06fe-4563-95c3-efa76975415b

Use populate action to add custom fields to the extended entity.

Reference: 
https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=bd0d8a36-b00b-44c8-bdcd-b2b4e4c86fd0

[image]

Comment: Thank you Hugues for your help. I re-made the fields into Attributes because Custom Fields change the table structure for all clients/tenants, and I am not sure Acumatica hosting companies will like it. Are there any benefits of using Custom Fields over Attributes on a Customer or Item levels?

Comment: Custom fields are much more flexible and require less time to implement.

Comment: So far, I found one benefit of Custom Fields: they are returned by GetlList function, while Attributes are not. On the other hand: Custom Fields are created on the whole Acumatica instance level (add fields to the database tables) and thus affect all tenants. They cannot be deleted if unused. DAC interface caused me grief when adding controls to the screen because project refused to re-compile, etc. Finally, Custom Fields, when added to Customers, affected all customers, and Attributes can be created for customers of specific classes. What is your take on these points?

Comment: Attributes have no programming interface so it's take it or leave it. You can customize behavior of custom fields by customer class or otherwise if necessary but with attributes you're limited to what's out of box.